# Java reading nodes recursively from xml returns just #text nodes

Tags: java, xml, recursion

I'm using this method to read all nodes from an xml file. But it seems my recursion is not working, becasue all nodes are #text nodes. How can I skip that and make it return my actual nodes ?

```
private void iterateNodes(Node node) {

    System.out.println("Node: " + node.getNodeName());

    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentode = nodeList.item(0);

        System.out.println(currentode.getNodeName());

        if (currentode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element element = (Element) currentode;
            iterateNodes(element);
        }
    }
}

public void run() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    String path = "others.xml";

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(path);

    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    iterateNodes(document.getDocumentElement());

}
```

Comment: I've set that as you said, but I didn't work.

Comment: Shouldnt `Node currentode = nodeList.item(0);` bet `Node currentode = nodeList.item(i);` - i.e. use **i** not **0**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code in `Node currentode  = nodeList.item(0)` <---- Change it with the iterator variable i.

```
private void iterateNodes(Node node) {

    System.out.println("Node: " + node.getNodeName());
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentode = nodeList.item(i);

        System.out.println(currentode.getNodeName());

        if (currentode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) currentode;
            iterateNodes(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I can't belive I didn't saw that mistake. Thank you. I have one more question. When printing them, how can I skip printing the #text nodes ?

Comment: if (currentode.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {

            Element element = (Element) currentode;

            iterateNodes(element);

        }

Comment: It worked by removing the line: `System.out.println(currentode.getNodeName());`